# Xcode c++ cant access file through code

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, build, filepath

I have added an image "padimage.png" to my resources folder and set `add to target` and `make copy if needed` checked. Then in my c++ code I have the following code to check if it can reach the file

```
std::ifstream my_file("padimage.png");
if (my_file.good())
{
    std::cout << "could read file \n";
} else {
    std::cout << "could not read file \n";
}
```

This fails meaning I can't reach the file. I have checked in the debug build folder and the image is there under the resources folder, I have also tried alternative paths to the file like `"resources/padimage.png"` || `Resources/padimage.png` || `../Resources/padimage.png` etc. etc.

I am fairly new to c++ still so I don't quite understand how it is suppose to find files or what path it searches relative to. Also I am sure this is quite an easy problem but I somehow can't solve it.

All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a suggestion from WhozCraig I have managed to get it working by using the root of the project and then creating a standalone file next to the application like so:

```
./padimage.png
```

however this is not ideal. This means I would have resources outside of the project.

But after some trial and error I managed to navigate into the programs package contents by using .app to the package name;

```
./ProjectName.app/Contents/Resources/padimage.png
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for your own sanity, do the following before anything else.

```
char wd[1024];
std::cout << getcwd(wd, sizeof(wd)) << std::endl;
```

You may be surprised at where you are, and thus why you can't open your file. When running from the IDE you can specify the location of your working directory under the Product/Edit Schemes... area of Xcode (among other places).

Comment: Thanks thats a nice way of knowing where the app runs, however I know where the app is running and the file is present in the package contents of the app. c++ still can't read it :( Do I have to put the path of the file from that point?

Comment: That must have hurt copying that file to such an odd place, becuase, for example, a simple test app I wrote has my build running out of :/Users/craig/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/main-aufmhkfprenvdlfaeqdocwohmsad/Build/Products/Debug. Is yours running from something similar ?

Comment: Yes, however finding that place wasn't that hard, run the app > right click the icon > show in finder. and I didn't move the file there, xcode already did that.

Comment: The only thing left I could suggest is "./resource/padimage.png", and note, the case *is* sensitive on your mac. I've not had this problem before, but have many-times run from a dir I wasn't expecting.

Comment: Yeah it's very odd. thanks for the input though. I geuss I'll keep trying till I find out whats wrong.

Comment: Does anyone know how to automatically copy this files into the DerivedData/AppName/Build/Products/Debug/ folder? I mean, it's so boring to copy files manually...